# Prevent unbounded mysqli queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working for a company that uses [this Mysqli php class to do mysql calls](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class).
The problem is, the previous programmer wasn't great about preventing unbounded queries. So there are things dispersed throughout the code like the following:

```
$db -> where('id',$_POST['id']);
$db -> delete('table');
```

This code is supposed to only delete one record where `id = $_POST['id']`. However, if `$_POST['id']` is empty, we've got problems. It then deletes the entire table. One solution to this problem would be to find all the places in the code where delete or update functions are called and then make sure that the where variable is actually set.

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!=''){
  $db -> where('id',$_POST['id']);
  $db -> delete('table');
}
```

But, that would take a lot of work because I know there are about 200 instances in the code. I'm hoping there might be a way to alter the following 2 functions to prevent them from executing unbound queries in the first place. Any help is appreciated!!

```
/**
 * Update query. Be sure to first call the "where" method.
 *
 * @param string $tableName The name of the database table to work with.
 * @param array  $tableData Array of data to update the desired row.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function update($tableName, $tableData)
{
    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return;

    $this->_query = "UPDATE " . self::$_prefix . $tableName ." SET ";

    $stmt = $this->_buildQuery (null, $tableData);
    $status = $stmt->execute();
    $this->reset();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->count = $stmt->affected_rows;

    return $status;
}

/**
 * Delete query. Call the "where" method first.
 *
 * @param string  $tableName The name of the database table to work with.
 * @param integer $numRows   The number of rows to delete.
 *
 * @return boolean Indicates success. 0 or 1.
 */
public function delete($tableName, $numRows = null)
{
    if ($this->isSubQuery)
        return;

    $this->_query = "DELETE FROM " . self::$_prefix . $tableName;

    $stmt = $this->_buildQuery($numRows);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->_stmtError = $stmt->error;
    $this->reset();

    return ($stmt->affected_rows > 0);
}

public function where($whereProp, $whereValue = 'DBNULL', $operator = '=', $cond = 'AND')
{
    // forkaround for an old operation api
    if (is_array($whereValue) && ($key = key($whereValue)) != "0") {
        $operator = $key;
        $whereValue = $whereValue[$key];
    }
    if (count($this->_where) == 0) {
        $cond = '';
    }
    $this->_where[] = array($cond, $whereProp, $operator, $whereValue);
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch the bad value when it's being passed to the `where` function, not later. That way it's easier to follow stack traces.

```
public function where($whereProp, $whereValue = 'DBNULL', $operator = '=', $cond = 'AND')
{
    if (is_null($whereValue) || trim($whereValue) == '') {
        throw new Exception('Cannot pass null or empty string as a condition to MysqliDb::where')
    }
    // ...
}
```

You could check through the `_where` protected property array inside of the `delete` function too, but it's not good practice to silently fail a method by doing a simple `return` out of the function. If you insist, though:

```
public function delete($tableName, $numRows = null)
{
    foreach ($this->_where as $w) {
        if (is_null($w[3]) || trim($w[3]) == '') {
            return;
            // or alternatively throw new Exception('...')
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I expect this is tricky for OP as some `->where` functions would not have a where value (such as outputting all rows from a table)

Comment: @Martin Then the `where` function wouldn't be called at all... All rows is simply `SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: Yeah, I should have thought that through a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning if this (the where clause) is empty?

https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/b3754d20bcebf07d65d552b2257696539a1cb144/MysqliDb.php#L1074

```
if (count($this->_where) == 0) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `$this->_where` would [still have a set of conditions](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/b3754d20bcebf07d65d552b2257696539a1cb144/MysqliDb.php#L739) even if the conditional passed to `MysqliDb::where` was `null`, so `return` would never happen. Also, you're returning without any failure or exception.

Answer (score 0):

please update to a latest stable version. this issue is fixed there.

where('val', unset) wont count as no condition.